# HTML javascript function to create element, but cannot find it with other function

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to program a scrambling puzzle in Javscript/HTML, in which I draw blue and red squares on an HTML file page. When the blue squares are clicked on, they move depending on their location with respect to the red square. I wrote a method that draws the squares and names them "blue1, blue2, blue3, red" etc. However, when I try to find the square named "red" with `getElementById("red")` and call `getBoundingClientRect()` on it, I get an error for

> trying to call `getBoundingClientRect()` on a null object.

I'm not sure why it would be `null` since I can see the square named "red" when I run my code.

Here is the code that draws the squares:

```
var board = [["blue3", "blue2"],["blue1", "red"]];
var dim = 2;
var width = 50;
var height = 50;

// add the squares 
function addSquares()
{
  for(var i = 0; i < dim; i++)
  {
    for(var j = 0; j < dim; j++)
    {
      // create square
      var label = j + i * dim; 
      var name = board[i][j];
      var div = document.createElement(name);
      div.style.width = width + "px";
      div.style.height = height + "px";
      div.style.left = width * j + "px";
      div.style.top = height * i + "px";
      div.style.position = "absolute";

      // determine color of square
      if(i != dim - 1 || j != dim - 1)
      {
      div.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
      }
      else
      {
        div.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      }

     document.getElementById("container").appendChild(div);

    // do something when clicked
    div.addEventListener("click", function(){getMove(this);});
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the code for `getMove()`, where there is an error once I call var `red = redelem.getBoundingClientRect();`

```
function getMove(elem) {
    var move = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    var redelem = document.getElementById('red');
    var red = redelem.getBoundingClientRect();

    mwcenter = 0.5 * (move.right + move.left);
    mhcenter = 0.5 * (move.bottom + move.top);
    rwcenter = 0.5 * (red.right + red.left);
    rhcenter = 0.5 * (red.bottom + red.top);

      if (mwcenter - rwcenter == 50 && mhcenter == rhcenter)
      {
        leftPress(elem);
        rightPress(redelem);
      }

      else if (mwcenter - rwcenter == -50 && mhcenter == rhcenter)
      {
        rightPress(elem);
        leftPress(redelem);
      }

      else if (mhcenter - rhcenter == 50 && mwcenter == rwcenter)
      {
        upPress(elem);
        downPress(redelem);
      }

      else if (mhcenter - rhcenter == -50 && mwcenter == rwcenter)
      {
        downPress(elem);
        upPress(redelem);
      }
}
```

Comment: you've never given it an id, therefore get element sby id returns null.

Answer (score 0):

"name" is not the same as "id".  getElementById does not find the div by looking for it's name, it gets it by id, so it will not find the element whose name is "red", without an id.  You have two options:

**Either:**

1. Use getElementByName() instead of getElementById(), using the following line instead of the one that causes the error:

   ```
   var redelem = document.getElementByName('red');
   ```

**Or:**

2. Give each of the divs an id:

You created the element and gave it a name, so you will also need to give it an id like this:

```
div.id = "red";
```

Actually, in your code it should be

```
div.id = name;
```

but I wanted my first example to be less confusing by showing you what you *literally* wanted for the red div. So, you can give your divs an id each and then you will be able to use getElementById successfuly.